# Find Array value ranges max and min value

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array how can i find the minimum and maximum value. i.e,

```
output must be min=0;max=15

 Array
(
[0] => 5-10
[1] => 10-15
[2] => 0-2
[3] => 15
)
```

Comment: have you observed the question? if you well understood the question sure you will have some work to work

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? If you well understood StackOverflow you will have already done some work yourself

Comment: @Mark Baker i have done some work if couldn't then i have asked the question.....i am expecting answers not your comments

Comment: @vamshi - If you have tried anything yourself, then it's always worth saying what you already tried in your question.... if not, then you may well get a lot of answers telling you to try exactly that

Comment: And yes, I understood your question, and have already provided you with an answer

Comment: @Mark Baker yes...the way you have commented initially it was something made me to reply with bit of angry because here we are asking the question when we doesn't know...You know everything and you feel everything a funny question we are not so experienced than you get a spontaneous thoughts and answers

Comment: I've already said why you should always say what you've tried, so that you don't have everybody telling you to do it again (because they don't know you've already tried it).... not saying that wastes both your time and ours

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$price_range=array("0-2","2-5","5-10","10-15","15");
foreach($price_range as $key=>$value){
$a=explode('-',$value);
if($a[0] != ''){$b[]= $a[0];}
if($a[1] != ''){$b[]= $a[1];}
}
echo 'min: '.$min=min($b);
echo 'max: '.$max=max($b);
?>
```

Comment: yeah thats the solution if its a string. The syntax in the question is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP `max()` and `min()` functions on the array, assuming it already evaluates the values before setting them in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and check indexes OR use min()/max() function from php

Comment: i need maximum and minimum values of that array

Comment: of the whole array or of the specific index?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a prime candidate for using [array_reduce()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$price_range = ["0-2","2-5","5-10","10-15","15"];

$min = array_reduce(
    $price_range,
    function ($carry, $value) {
        return min(array_merge(explode('-',$value), [$carry]));
    },
    PHP_INT_MAX
);

$max = array_reduce(
    $price_range,
    function ($carry, $value) {
        return max(array_merge(explode('-',$value), [$carry]));
    },
    -PHP_INT_MAX
);

echo 'min: '.$min, PHP_EOL;
echo 'max: '.$max, PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
$price=array();
$price_range=array("0-2","2-5","5-10","10-15","15");
foreach($price_range as $key=>$value){
$a=explode('-',$value);
array_push($price,$a[0]);
}
echo 'min: '.$min=min($price);
echo 'max: '.$max=max($price);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input_range = ['0-2','2-5','5-10','10-15','15'];

$collect = [];

foreach($input_range as $range)
{
    $collect = array_merge($collect, explode('-', $range));
}

$min = min($collect);
$max = max($collect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make an use of `array_walk` along with the `min` and `max` function as

```
$price_range = array("0-2","2-5","5-10","10-15","15");
$result = array();
array_walk($price_range,function($v,$k)use(&$result){ 
    $result = array_merge($result,explode('-', $v));
});
echo "Min value = ".min($result)." & Max value = ".max($result);
```

Comment: (_FYI:You can accept or upvote the answer which really helps you_)